# What the rest of the division $5^{21}$ by $127$?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

What the rest of the division $5^{21}$ by $127$?

Comment: I think the word you want is "remainder".

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: If by "rest" you mean remainder, then yes.

Comment: Yes, I'm Brazilian

Comment: (+1) You should remove your work from the question and make it an answer. This cuts down on the unanswered questions on the site, and I know I'll be glad to upvote the answer. It is explicitly permitted (even encouraged) to answer your own questions here, though you won't be able to accept it for three days.

Comment: @CameronBuie Okay, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9):

Answer:$$5^{21}=(5^3)^7\\5^3=125
\\125\equiv-2\pmod{127}
\\125\equiv-2\pmod{127}
\\(5^3)^7\equiv(-2)^7\pmod{127}
\\5^{21}\equiv-128\pmod{127}
\\5^{21}\equiv-1\pmod{127}
\\5^{21}\equiv126\pmod{127}$$

> Soon, the rest is 126