# Divisibility and the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

While studying the Fibonacci sequence I encountered this problem in the handout, and I can not understand how to do it.

> Show that if the Fibonacci sequence has a term divisible by a natural number $m$, then there are infinitely many such terms.

Answer (score 9):

The [duplication identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for the Fibonacci numbers states:
$$
    F_{2m} = F_m \left( F_m + 2 F_{m-1} \right)
$$

Hence, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if $F_m$ is divisible by $k$, every element of the sequence $F_{2m}, F_{4m}, \ldots, F_{2^r m}, \ldots$ is also  divisible by $k$.

Comment: Sorry but the way that I do not understand a way of answering this question

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Since Fibonacci numbers are integers, $F_{2m}$ is an integer multiple of $F_{m}$. Hence if $F_m$ is divisible by som $k$, so is the $F_{2k}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the same as $F_{2n}=L_nF_n$ where $L_n$ is a [Lucas Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number).

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Consider the sequence modulo $m$. This sequence is (immediately) periodic.

---

I'm assuming you know what modular arithmetic is.

Claim: The sequence modulo $m$ is immediately periodic.

Proof:

1. Every term of the sequence is uniquely defined by the 2 terms preceding it. Hence, given any pair of consecutive terms, we know what the rest of the terms are.
2. Consider pair of consecutive terms taken modulo $m$. There are $m \times m$ possibilities for the pairs. Since this is finite, and we have infinitely many pairs, there must be (at least) 1 pair that repeats (at least once). From the first observation, this shows that the sequence is (eventually) periodic. [The period is a factor of the difference of the indices of the terms.]
3. In fact, if we know what 2 consecutive terms are, then we know what the previous term is, and hence every term that comes before it. Thus, the sequence is immediately periodic.

Comment: I began my studies in the theory of numbers this year, still do not know modular arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand the idea;

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I honestly do not understand how to do it, how to solve the problem.

Comment: @marcelo: I am puzzled. You seemed to be doing modular arithmetic just fine in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/466835/11619).  What's the deal here? Are you in high school? I find it hard to believe that a college level elementary course in numbre theory wouldn't get to congruences, i.e. modular arithmetic very quickly.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior I added more details for the periodic part, assuming that you know modular arithmetic. Is this clear now?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen
I'm sorry. Studied modular arithmetic just one day, so this issue but have not learned to do demonstrations using the.

Answer (score 1):

I thought so:$$\fbox{Lemma 1: $a\mid b\Longleftrightarrow u_a\mid u_b$, in Fibonacci sequence}$$We have $m\mid u_n$ and $\exists a\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a\geq n$ such that $n\mid a$ therefore, by Lemma 1: $u_n\mid u_a$; and if $n\mid a\Longrightarrow n\mid ak\;\;\;\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ soon $$u_n\mid u_{ak}\;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$$ as $m\mid u_n$ and $u_n\mid u_{ak}\;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ then $m\mid u_{ak}\;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ Since $k$ can take any natural $u_{ak}$ has infinite values.​​$\;\;\;\;\Box$$$$$Correct?

Comment: I don't understand how the lemma could be true? The second entry in the Fibonacci sequence is $=1$ and thus divides all the others, even those with an odd index?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think the $\implies$ is true (I show that in my answer), but the other direction is not (as you have explained).

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
F_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}
$$
we also have
$$
F_{mn}=\frac{\phi^{mn}-(-1/\phi)^{mn}}{\sqrt5}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{F_{mn}}{F_n}
&=\frac{\phi^{mn}-(-1/\phi)^{mn}}{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\phi^{(m-k)n}(-1/\phi)^{(k-1)n}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\left(\phi^{(m-k)n}(-1/\phi)^{(k-1)n}+\phi^{(k-1)n}(-1/\phi)^{(m-k)n}\right)\\
&\hphantom{=}+(-1)^{(m-1)n/2}[m\text{ is odd}]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}(-1)^{(k-1)n}\left(\phi^{(m-2k+1)n}+(-1/\phi)^{(m-2k+1)n}\right)\\
&\hphantom{=}+(-1)^{(m-1)n/2}[m\text{ is odd}]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}(-1)^{(k-1)n}L_{(m-2k+1)n}\\
&\hphantom{=}+(-1)^{(m-1)n/2}[m\text{ is odd}]\\
\end{align}
$$
where $L_n$ are [Lucas Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) and $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

The important thing is that $\dfrac{F_{mn}}{F_n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.